# "Can't get valid Device ID" error message

Tags: troubleshooting, miui, xiaomi, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I am getting this error message on a Xiaomi Redmi Note 2:

> Can't get valid Device ID
>
> Invalid Device ID: null
>
> Device ID must be valid IMEI or MAC address. Without device id, some
> account and cloud features will be unavailable.

It pops up randomly, sometimes it appears several times (I click Ok to dismiss it) in a minute, sometimes it doesn't show up in about an hour. It interrupts apps and **the phone (and all phone related features like sms) does not work**, as it doesn't detect the sim card, which actually works, as I have tested it in another phone.

I woke up and this started happening suddenly. Usually the phone updates apps at night, so that might be it.

The following information might come useful:

- Model number: Redmi Note 2.
- Android Version: 5.0.2 LRX22G
- Android Security Patch Level: 2016-04-01.
- MIUI version: MIUI 7.4 by xiaomi.eu 6.5.5 | Beta

Note: This is the issue same issue as this one: http://en.miui.com/thread-109909-1-1.html

The solution given there does not fix the problem.

Comment: Is your device rooted? Do you use any kind of permission manager, and have revoked the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission from some app that might "need" it? Because that's the permission required to access the IMEI.

Comment: @Izzy As far as I know, Xiaomi devices (at least redmi note) come rooted. I have no permission manager other than Miui's.

Comment: OK, and have you restricted some app in the way outlined? I'm not sure how much Miui's permission manager permits :)

Comment: @Izzy I don't think so. This started happening without me doing anything special.

Comment: Was an idea – unfortunately the only one I had.